# Qt GUI Dialog Initialization Confusion

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am learning GUI coding with Qt and hope to clear up some confusion on my part.  When I create a dialog with Qt Creator it creates code for me like this...

```
#ifndef LISTDIALOG_H
#define LISTDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_listdialog.h"  //Q1:Why was this auto paced in cpp file instead of h file?

//Q2: This is what I'm really confused about.
//Is Ui namespace wrapping ui_listdialog class or the ListDialog class? 
namespace Ui {
    class ListDialog;
}

class ListDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ListDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);   //Q3: Why is this constructor explicit?
    ~ListDialog();


//CUSTOM FUNCTIONALITY NOT ADDED BY CREATOR (IGNORE FOR MY POST)
private slots:
  void addItem();
  void editItem();
  void deleteItem();
//END CUSTOM FUNCTIONALITY


private:
    Ui::ListDialog *ui;     //Placed on heap instead of stack.
};

#endif // LISTDIALOG_H
```

There are things in the above code that differ from my 3 Qt books (all 3 out of date and ignore Creator).

My main confusion comes from Q2. Is "Ui" wrapping "ui_listdialog.h" or the class I have posted here ( class ListDialog )?  The syntax seems to imply to me that it is wrapping the latter but I feel it must be actually wrapping the ui_listdialog.h class instead.  Very confused about this. Can someone explain this clearly?

I also don't understand why the constructor was made explicit by Creator. I have not seen that in any of the 3 books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1. The #include is placed in the .cpp to avoid too many dependencies in the header file. This shortens compilation time, because if you change the dialog, the only thing you have to recompile is the .cpp and not everything that includes your header file. In general, if a forward declaration of a class is enough (i.e. you only have a pointer or a reference to it in your class), then it's better not to #include the class's definition.

Q2. Ui is a namespace that contains a *different* class called ListDialog. You can open the header file and see the definition of this other class. A bit confusing until you get used to it.

Q3. It's a good habit to use the `explicit` keyword with constructors that take a single parameter. Otherwise the constructor can also be used as an automatic conversion operator, and this can cause problems if you're not aware of it. For example, if you have a function that takes a ListDialog parameter, and you pass a QWidget * parameter, it may call the constructor when in fact you want the compiler to shout (invalid parameter).

Comment: The Q2 thing is kinda neat, actually.  You have _your_ class, `ListDialog`, and then the container class `Ui::ListDialog`.  That way your class still has the name you gave it, but most of the _Ui_ added stuff is hidden-away in the contained object with almost the same name.

Comment: Small correction for Q3: It should read ListDialog (no pointer)

Comment: Thanks omrib for the great answers (to the point and clear). About Q2, how is it that the compiler does not get confused about my true ListDialog class (shown here) and the "other' ListDialog class which is wrapped by the namespace? As for Q3, your example is one where the constructor takes a more specific form (ListDialog) and you want to prevent it taking a more general form (QWidget).  That makes sense to me.  In the code i posted the explicit constructor takes a QWidget wich is the most general form for GUI so I'm wondering if explicit still makes sense in that regard or is it just habit.

Comment: @user440297 Namespaces avoid name clashes - that's their purpose in life. So you can imagine that a class in a namespace is actually called "ns::classname", and the compiler cannot get confused. About Q3, as Frank Osterfeld wrote, there was a mistake in the answer. The problem is with `void func(ListDialog ld)` where you have a call in the code `func(&widget)` and you want the compiler to shout at you instead of constructing a ListDialog out of the widget. It's not a question of downcasting.

Comment: Right, I know why namespaces exist, what confuses me is... namespace Ui { class ListDialog; } right before my ListDialog class declaration. Somehow my ListDialog is not added to the namespaces but instead some "other" invisible ListDialog class is added to the namespace.  I was just wondering about the magic behind this.  I would think that the syntax of how you normally add a class to a namespace would suggest that my ListDialog class would be added to the namespace and not some other ListDialog class defined who knows where.

Comment: I see what you mean. But the only way to put something inside a namespace is to define it inside the curly brackets. It is not possible to say "please put the following into the namespace" or "please put what I've defined into the namespace". The reason you have `namespace Ui { class ListDialog; }` is that somewhere else you have `namespace Ui { class ListDialog { ... }; }`. You can't move definitions from, into or between namespaces.

Comment: That's just it. I used Ctrl+click on ListDialog in namespace Ui { class ListDialog; } and I saw the code for class Ui_ListDialog{...}; It was not enclosed by C++ namespace syntax but Qt namespace macros. No matter,assuming that those macros get translated to C++ namespace tags around the class...I still don't get why in my ListDialog class there is the namespace Ui { class ListDialog; } code which at first glance attempts to redefine the namespace (can't be done). I don't understand what the point is to having that code in my class since you norm don't do that to use an existing namespace.

Comment: ...if someplace else I already have namespace Ui { class ListDialog { ... }; then why do I also need namespace Ui { class ListDialog; } again in my class?

Comment: @user440297 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1599/discussion-between-omrib-and-user440297)

Answer (score 0):

The `ui_listdialog.h` contains implementation to generate your user interface based on Qt Designer. It isn't necessary when declaring the class -- that's why the file was `#include`d in the `.cpp` (Q1). Without the `ui_listdialog.h` in the header, the class declaration is necessary (Q2).

As for Q3, it's probably there to make you use the constructor syntax. Else, you could write misleading statements like

```
ListDialog dialog = parentDialog ;
```

Comment: Thanks swongu, but I think you miss understood my questions.  For Q1, I wasn't asking why you need to include ui_listdialog.h.  I understand that the gui xml sheet is translated to cpp an that the translated cpp is in ui_listdialog.  I was mereley wondering why Creator placed the include statement in the ListDialog.cpp file instead of the ListDialog.h file (I moved it to the .h file above).  Not a huge deal though.  As for Q2, My question is which class is the Ui namespace wrapping?  The ui_listdialog class or the ListDialog class?  I find the syntax confusing.

Comment: Ahh, omrib has essentially what I wanted to write here. For completeness though, the ui_listdialog.h is only necessary in the implementation details (.cpp), and while moving it to the header is fine, you're including more than what's sufficient (forward declaration). As for Q2, the Ui namespace is wrapping the generated class ListDialog, a different class than the one in your code. The syntax is a forward declaration, taking the namespace into consideration.